# python introspection; see which method was called, who called it, and which parameters they passed it from the main method

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following is an attempt I have been making at introspection on a "simulated operating system" in python.

```
def tracefunc(frame, event, arg, indent=[0]):
  if event == "call" and frame.f_code.co_name in methods:
    if frame.f_code.co_name != 'FetchOperand':
      print("====================================")
      print("CALL FUNCTION: %s()\nARGUMENTS: %s" % (frame.f_code.co_name, frame.f_code.co_varnames))
      print('====================================')
  return tracefunc
sys.settrace(tracefunc)
```

It is contained in a block that looks something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  vm = OS()
  while(interrupt not shutdown):
    try:
      vm.read_interrupt()
      vm.execute_program()
      # some case statement
```

What the ultimate goal is is to print out any method's execution that is incapsulated within my VM object. I want to see where it was called, who called it, what the parameters passed in were, and what variables it itself modified. I also need a way to specify these things called `output parameters`, which will be a list. Ideally, if it modified an array, it would print the index and the item and that index. Here is an example

```
$my_program: 4

==============================
SYSTEM CALL() method called
called by READ INTERRUPT()

--> Arguments:
  arg[0]: 4 <type 'int'>

--> Output Parameters:
  gpr[0]: OK

return value: 'OK'

==============================
PUT CHARACTER() method called
called by SYSTEM CALL()

--> Arguments:
  None

--> output parameters:
  gpr[0]: OK
  gpr[1]: 3

--> modified variables:
memory:
  index: 4003
  old value: 0
  new value: 3

return value: 'OK'
==============================
```

by the way, do not feel too bound to my original method of doing things. I welcome any suggestions you may have.

Can anyone suggest a method by which to achieve such introspection?

Comment: Have you looked at the `inspect` module and/or the `traceback.extract_stack` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
import traceback
traceback.print_stack()
```

that should tell you all that great stuff ...